# Collapsible vertical sidebar menu icon with submenu

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

A collapsible sidebar menu, where I'm looking for a plus (+) sign to toggle to a minus (-) sign. When the sidebar menu opens and toggles the same operation happened again.

From the documentation and community code resource, I'm able to toggle the collapse menu, but I'm looking for a right-side plus (+) icon also changed from a plus (+) to a minus(-) icon

I used bootstrap icons and for the plus and dash signs following classes are used respectively `<i class="bi bi-plus"></i>` , `<i class="bi bi-dash"></i>`

```js
;
(function() {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    document.querySelectorAll('.g-sidebar .nav-link').forEach(function(element) {

      element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

        let nextEl = element.nextElementSibling;
        let parentEl = element.parentElement;

        if (nextEl) {
          e.preventDefault();
          let sidebarNavCollapse = new bootstrap.Collapse(nextEl);

          if (nextEl.classList.contains('show')) {
            sidebarNavCollapse.hide();
          } else {
            sidebarNavCollapse.show();
            // find other submenus with class=show
            let opened_submenu = parentEl.parentElement.querySelector('.submenu.show');
            // if it exists, then close all of them
            if (opened_submenu) {
              new bootstrap.Collapse(opened_submenu);
            }

          }
        }

      });
    })

  });
})();
```

```css
.g-aside {
  background-color: #8c8c8c;
  width: 260px;
}

.nav {
  --bs-nav-link-padding-x: 1rem;
  --bs-nav-link-padding-y: 0.5rem;
  --bs-nav-link-color: var(--bs-link-color);
  --bs-nav-link-hover-color: var(--bs-link-hover-color);
  --bs-nav-link-disabled-color: #6c757d;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.submenu>li {
  list-style: none;
}

.g-sidebar .nav-link {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  font-family: quicksand, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  width: calc(260px - 1rem);
  transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
  list-style: none!;
}

.g-sidebar .nav-link p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 1.4rem;
  display: inline-block;
}

.g-sidebar .nav-link p i,
.g-sidebar .nav-link p span {
  right: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<aside class="g-aside">
  <!--Sidebar Area-->
  <div class="g-sidebar-area">
    <nav class="g-sidebar py-2 mb-4">
      <ul class="nav flex-column" id="nav_accordion">

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <i class="bi bi-person-fill"></i>
            <p>Agents</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item has-submenu">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <i class="bi bi-columns-gap"></i>
            <p>Dashboard <i class="bi bi-plus"></i></p>
          </a>
          <ul class="submenu collapse">

            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item has-submenu">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <i class="bi bi-box-fill"></i>
            <p>IVR <i class="bi bi-plus"></i></p>
          </a>
          <ul class="submenu collapse">
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <i class="bi bi-grid-1x2-fill"></i>
            <p>Page <span class="badge bg-primary">12</span></p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <!--                    <li class="ms-3 mt-3">PROMOTION</li>-->
        <li class="nav-item has-submenu">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <i class="bi bi-record-btn-fill"></i>
            <p>Campaign <i class="bi bi-plus"></i></p>
          </a>
          <ul class="submenu collapse">
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item has-submenu">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <i class="bi bi-file-earmark-text-fill"></i>
            <p>Report <i class="bi bi-plus"></i></p>
          </a>
          <ul class="submenu collapse">
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item has-submenu">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <i class="bi bi-file-plus-fill"></i>
            <p>New Report <i class="bi bi-plus"></i></p>
          </a>
          <ul class="submenu collapse">
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <i class="bi bi-record-btn-fill"></i>
            <p> Skill </p>
          </a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <i class="bi bi-voicemail"></i>
            <p>Voice Mail </p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item has-submenu">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="bi bi-chat-right-text-fill"></i>
                            <p>Chat <i class="bi bi-plus"></i></p></a>
          <ul class="submenu collapse">
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item has-submenu">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="bi bi-envelope-fill"></i>
                            <p>Email <i class="bi bi-plus"></i></p></a>
          <ul class="submenu collapse">
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item has-submenu">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="bi bi-file-earmark-text-fill"></i>
                            <p>SMS <i class="bi bi-plus"></i></p></a>
          <ul class="submenu collapse">
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>


        <li class="nav-item has-submenu">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <i class="bi bi-window-stack"></i>
            <p>CRM <i class="bi bi-plus"></i></p>
          </a>
          <ul class="submenu collapse">
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item has-submenu">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <i class="bi bi-telephone-inbound-fill"></i>
            <p>CRM Inbound <i class="bi bi-plus"></i></p>
          </a>
          <ul class="submenu collapse">
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: does expanding add a property like `expanded` to the html element? because it can fix your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try querying for `bi-plus` and if that doesn't work query `bi-dash` and flag `self`. Then you can remove all dashes and replace with plus, and depending on `flag` add plus or dash

```js
;
(function() {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    document.querySelectorAll('.g-sidebar .nav-link').forEach(function(element) {

      element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        let self=false

        let nextEl = element.nextElementSibling;
        let parentEl = element.parentElement;
        let childImg = element.querySelector('.bi-plus');
        if(!childImg){
            self = true;
            childImg = element.querySelector('.bi-dash');
        }

        if (nextEl) {
          e.preventDefault();
          let sidebarNavCollapse = new bootstrap.Collapse(nextEl);

          if (nextEl.classList.contains('show')) {
            sidebarNavCollapse.hide();
          } else {
            document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link .bi-dash').forEach(function(elem){
              if (elem!==childImg) {
                elem.classList.add('bi-plus')
                elem.classList.remove('bi-dash')
              }
            })
            if(!self){
              childImg.classList.remove('bi-plus')
              childImg.classList.add('bi-dash')
            } else {
              childImg.classList.remove('bi-dash')
              childImg.classList.add('bi-plus')
            }
            sidebarNavCollapse.show();
            // find other submenus with class=show
            let opened_submenu = parentEl.parentElement.querySelector('.submenu.show');
            // if it exists, then close all of them
            if (opened_submenu) {
              new bootstrap.Collapse(opened_submenu);
            }

          }
        }

      });
    })

  });
})();
```

```css
.g-aside {
  background-color: #8c8c8c;
  width: 260px;
}

.nav {
  --bs-nav-link-padding-x: 1rem;
  --bs-nav-link-padding-y: 0.5rem;
  --bs-nav-link-color: var(--bs-link-color);
  --bs-nav-link-hover-color: var(--bs-link-hover-color);
  --bs-nav-link-disabled-color: #6c757d;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.submenu>li {
  list-style: none;
}

.g-sidebar .nav-link {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  font-family: quicksand, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  width: calc(260px - 1rem);
  transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
  list-style: none!;
}

.g-sidebar .nav-link p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 1.4rem;
  display: inline-block;
}

.g-sidebar .nav-link p i,
.g-sidebar .nav-link p span {
  right: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<aside class="g-aside">
  <!--Sidebar Area-->
  <div class="g-sidebar-area">
    <nav class="g-sidebar py-2 mb-4">
      <ul class="nav flex-column" id="nav_accordion">

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <i class="bi bi-person-fill"></i>
            <p>Agents</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item has-submenu">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <i class="bi bi-columns-gap"></i>
            <p>Dashboard <i class="bi bi-plus"></i></p>
          </a>
          <ul class="submenu collapse">

            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item has-submenu">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <i class="bi bi-box-fill"></i>
            <p>IVR <i class="bi bi-plus"></i></p>
          </a>
          <ul class="submenu collapse">
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <i class="bi bi-grid-1x2-fill"></i>
            <p>Page <span class="badge bg-primary">12</span></p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <!--                    <li class="ms-3 mt-3">PROMOTION</li>-->
        <li class="nav-item has-submenu">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <i class="bi bi-record-btn-fill"></i>
            <p>Campaign <i class="bi bi-plus"></i></p>
          </a>
          <ul class="submenu collapse">
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item has-submenu">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <i class="bi bi-file-earmark-text-fill"></i>
            <p>Report <i class="bi bi-plus"></i></p>
          </a>
          <ul class="submenu collapse">
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item has-submenu">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <i class="bi bi-file-plus-fill"></i>
            <p>New Report <i class="bi bi-plus"></i></p>
          </a>
          <ul class="submenu collapse">
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <i class="bi bi-record-btn-fill"></i>
            <p> Skill </p>
          </a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <i class="bi bi-voicemail"></i>
            <p>Voice Mail </p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item has-submenu">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="bi bi-chat-right-text-fill"></i>
                            <p>Chat <i class="bi bi-plus"></i></p></a>
          <ul class="submenu collapse">
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item has-submenu">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="bi bi-envelope-fill"></i>
                            <p>Email <i class="bi bi-plus"></i></p></a>
          <ul class="submenu collapse">
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item has-submenu">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="bi bi-file-earmark-text-fill"></i>
                            <p>SMS <i class="bi bi-plus"></i></p></a>
          <ul class="submenu collapse">
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>


        <li class="nav-item has-submenu">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <i class="bi bi-window-stack"></i>
            <p>CRM <i class="bi bi-plus"></i></p>
          </a>
          <ul class="submenu collapse">
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item has-submenu">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <i class="bi bi-telephone-inbound-fill"></i>
            <p>CRM Inbound <i class="bi bi-plus"></i></p>
          </a>
          <ul class="submenu collapse">
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 2):

**CSS Only Solution**

If you wire up the menus as shown in the [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/collapse/) then you won't need the custom JavaScript and can toggle the icons using only css. To do this, we only need to add a `data-bs-toggle` attribute, an id, and an href.  Compare the original and modified code below for the changes that must be made to each of the collapsible menus.

**Original:**

```
  <a class="nav-link">
    <i class="bi bi-columns-gap"></i>
    <p>Dashboard
      <i class="bi bi-plus"></i>
    </p>
  </a>
  <ul class="submenu collapse">
  ...
```

**Modified:**

```
  <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#dashboard" data-bs-toggle="collapse">
    <i class="bi bi-columns-gap"></i>
    <p>Dashboard
      <i class="bi bi-plus"></i>
      <i class="bi bi-dash"></i>
    </p>
  </a>
  <ul class="submenu collapse" id="dashboard">
  ...
```

When a menu is opened, Bootstrap adds the collapsed class to the nav-link. And we can use that class to show or hide the first and last icon.

**CSS:**

```
.nav-link.collapsed i:first-child {
  display: inline;
}

.nav-link:not(.collapsed) i:first-child {
  display: none;
}

.nav-link.collapsed i:last-child {
  display: none;
}

.nav-link:not(.collapsed) i:last-child {
  display: inline;
}
```

```css
.nav-link.collapsed i:first-child {
  display: inline;
}

.nav-link:not(.collapsed) i:first-child {
  display: none;
}

.nav-link.collapsed i:last-child {
  display: none;
}

.nav-link:not(.collapsed) i:last-child {
  display: inline;
}

/* original style */

.g-aside {
  background-color: #8c8c8c;
  width: 260px;
}

.nav {
  --bs-nav-link-padding-x: 1rem;
  --bs-nav-link-padding-y: 0.5rem;
  --bs-nav-link-color: var(--bs-link-color);
  --bs-nav-link-hover-color: var(--bs-link-hover-color);
  --bs-nav-link-disabled-color: #6c757d;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.submenu>li {
  list-style: none;
}

.g-sidebar .nav-link {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  font-family: quicksand, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  width: calc(260px - 1rem);
  transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
  list-style: none!;
}

.g-sidebar .nav-link p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 1.4rem;
  display: inline-block;
}

.g-sidebar .nav-link p i,
.g-sidebar .nav-link p span {
  right: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<aside class="g-aside">
  <div class="g-sidebar-area">
    <nav class="g-sidebar py-2 mb-4">
      <ul class="nav flex-column" id="nav_accordion">


        <li class="nav-item has-submenu">
          <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#dashboard" data-bs-toggle="collapse">
            <i class="bi bi-columns-gap"></i>
            <p>Dashboard
              <i class="bi bi-plus"></i>
              <i class="bi bi-dash"></i>
            </p>
          </a>
          <ul class="submenu collapse" id="dashboard">

            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item has-submenu">
          <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#ivr" data-bs-toggle="collapse">
            <i class="bi bi-box-fill"></i>
            <p>IVR
              <i class="bi bi-plus"></i>
              <i class="bi bi-dash"></i>
            </p>
          </a>
          <ul class="submenu collapse" id="ivr">
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-journal-check"></i>
                <p>Submenu item 1</p>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <!-- other menus not shown -->


      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</aside>


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```